# bad font quality in small fontsize wpf

Tags: wpf, fonts, text-rendering

hi i changed font in my application but i think when app is running font quality is bad, As you can see in the picture in VS font quality is good but in runtime its bad is there any way to fix this? 
when i increase fontsize (like 100) quality is very good but when i use 14 its bad.

VS:
[image: VS]

Runtime:
[image: Runtime]

Comment: Try changing TextFormattingMode to Display, it is recommended for small text. [Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2009/10/21/new-wpf-features-textformattingmode-for-clear-text/)

Comment: ok i will test it

Comment: both these images are "mostly not the part we should be looking at", can you show crops with only the text, without any resizing?